# phalcon controller indexAction break down

Tags: php, phalcon

I am new into Phalcon framework. I just got the basic idea about it. Every controller has methods with multiple specific actions. I wrote a huge indexAction method but now I want to break it down with multiple private method so that I can reuse those functionality. But when I try to create any method without action suffix, it returns error(Page Not Found).
 How can I break it down into multiple methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->someMethod();
    }

    public function someMethod()
    {
        //do your things
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Controllers must have the suffix “Controller” **while actions the suffix “Action”**. A sample of a controller is as follows:

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {

    }

    public function showAction($year, $postTitle)
    {

    }
}
```

For calling another method, you would use it straight forward

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo $this->showAction();
    }

    private function showAction()
    {
        return "show";
    }
}
```

[Docs](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/controllers.html).

Comment: I understand that i have to create actions with Action suffix. But I want to break down my indexAction into multiple methods so that I can reduce the size of indexAction method and reuse those methods for next time

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want? The answer seems trivial to me.

```
class YourController extends Phalcon\Mvc\Controller
{
    // this method can be called externally because it has the "Action" suffix
    public function indexAction()
    {
       $this->customStuff('value');
       $this->more();
    }

    // this method is only used inside this controller
    private function customStuff($parameter)
    {

    }

    private function more()
    {

    }
}
```